# Undefined reference when compiling RemotePad

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint

I am trying to compile RemotePad Server on Linux Mint 12 and I am getting the following error during make:

```
gcc -lXtst -lX11 -lm  -o remotepad remotepad.o ucs2keysym.o
remotepad.o: In function `handleKeyEvent':
/home/joe/Downloads/RemotePad Server/X11/remotepad.c:369: undefined reference to `XKeysymToKeycode'
/home/joe/Downloads/RemotePad Server/X11/remotepad.c:371: undefined reference to `XTestFakeKeyEvent'
remotepad.o: In function `simulateKeyWithUnichar':
/home/joe/Downloads/RemotePad Server/X11/remotepad.c:379: undefined reference to `XKeysymToKeycode'
/home/joe/Downloads/RemotePad Server/X11/remotepad.c:399: undefined reference to `XTestFakeKeyEvent'
/home/joe/Downloads/RemotePad Server/X11/remotepad.c:404: undefined reference to `XTestFakeKeyEvent'
/home/joe/Downloads/RemotePad Server/X11/remotepad.c:403: undefined reference to `XTestFakeKeyEvent'
/home/joe/Downloads/RemotePad Server/X11/remotepad.c:401: undefined reference to `XTestFakeKeyEvent'
/home/joe/Downloads/RemotePad Server/X11/remotepad.c:389: undefined reference to `XKeysymToKeycode'
/home/joe/Downloads/RemotePad Server/X11/remotepad.c:394: undefined reference to `XKeysymToKeycode'
/home/joe/Downloads/RemotePad Server/X11/remotepad.c:398: undefined reference to `XTestFakeKeyEvent'
/home/joe/Downloads/RemotePad Server/X11/remotepad.c:396: undefined reference to `XTestFakeKeyEvent'
/home/joe/Downloads/RemotePad Server/X11/remotepad.c:391: undefined reference to `XKeysymToKeycode'
remotepad.o: In function `handleKeyEvent':
/home/joe/Downloads/RemotePad Server/X11/remotepad.c:365: undefined reference to `XBell'
remotepad.o: In function `main':
/home/joe/Downloads/RemotePad Server/X11/remotepad.c:125: undefined reference to `XOpenDisplay'
/home/joe/Downloads/RemotePad Server/X11/remotepad.c:130: undefined reference to `XTestQueryExtension'
/home/joe/Downloads/RemotePad Server/X11/remotepad.c:143: undefined reference to `XCreateWindow'
/home/joe/Downloads/RemotePad Server/X11/remotepad.c:148: undefined reference to `XDisplayKeycodes'
/home/joe/Downloads/RemotePad Server/X11/remotepad.c:150: undefined reference to `XGetKeyboardMapping'
/home/joe/Downloads/RemotePad Server/X11/remotepad.c:194: undefined reference to `XGetWindowAttributes'
/home/joe/Downloads/RemotePad Server/X11/remotepad.c:317: undefined reference to `XGetWindowAttributes'
/home/joe/Downloads/RemotePad Server/X11/remotepad.c:302: undefined reference to `XFlush'
/home/joe/Downloads/RemotePad Server/X11/remotepad.c:259: undefined reference to `XTestFakeButtonEvent'
/home/joe/Downloads/RemotePad Server/X11/remotepad.c:260: undefined reference to `XTestFakeButtonEvent'
/home/joe/Downloads/RemotePad Server/X11/remotepad.c:284: undefined reference to `XTestFakeButtonEvent'
/home/joe/Downloads/RemotePad Server/X11/remotepad.c:233: undefined reference to `XTestFakeRelativeMotionEvent'
/home/joe/Downloads/RemotePad Server/X11/remotepad.c:126: undefined reference to `XDisplayName'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [remotepad] Error 1
```

I've googled and it says to make sure the Xsts package is installed which I did.

```
/home/joe $ ls /usr/lib/libXtst*
/usr/lib/libXtst.a  /usr/lib/libXtst.so  /usr/lib/libXtst.so.6  /usr/lib/libXtst.so.6.1.0
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Best to use: `gcc remotepad.o ucs2keysym.o -o remotepad -lXtst -lX11 -lm` for argument ordering. The undefined references are definitely in the X11 library. Perhaps add `-L/usr/X11/lib` - or wherever the X libraries are found.

Comment: Worked!  Thank you.  joe@joe-Inspiron-1720 ~/Downloads/RemotePad Server/X11 $ gcc remotepad.o ucs2keysym.o -o remotepad -lXtst -lX11 -lm -L/usr/lib

Comment: no go. after doing this I run make and get the error : make: Nothing to be done for `all'.